# Is frequent releasing of new books a good alternative to doing promotions?

Tags: self-publishing, marketing

Is it true that releasing several well-written books consecutively/frequently will lead to sales without any need to do promotions?

I have heard some indie-publishing authors/pundits say that a better (or alternative) way to push your books and have high sales is simply by releasing books frequently, and promotion is thus unnecessary. One particular strong advocate of this notion is an author called Dean W. Smith. In fact, he claims that the need for marketing/promotions is "a myth," and that all you have do is write and publish frequently and your books will promote themselves as people find them.

I would like to know if this is true, because I notice that the man has never provided any actual evidence to support his assertion. Does merely writing and releasing (good) books frequently work? And if so, why would that be? As i understand it, when a book is published on Amazon by an unknown author without doing any promotion of it, it merely sits there and sinks into the ocean and it will never get sold. Why would it make any difference if you add more books in the same way? Wouldn't they all just sink into the abyss?

Or perhaps what they mean is that doing so simply increases your odds of one of your books being accidentally seen by a customer (just like buying many lottery tickets increases your chances at winning a lottery). Is that simply what they mean? Because they never actually elaborate on how exactly they are claiming it works.

Comment: Do you have a link to the source? I'm wondering how Dean W. Smith justifies his theory and why he doesn't apply it himself (he has very few books on Amazon).

Comment: Here's a link: https://blog.karenwoodward.org/2012/10/the-best-way-to-build-writers-platform.html

Comment: Also, could you give me a suggestion as to why this question has almost zero views and no replies? I thought it was a very interesting and relevant question to most authors?

Comment: @user394536 This site is a lot less active than it used to be, so don't take it personally. It may well be the case that there simply aren't any active users left who have enough self-publishing experience to know whether this is true or not. I myself have only self-published a single book (it did badly, and for good reason), so I couldn't tell you whether self-publishing several leads to increased sales.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it true that the need for marketing/promoting one's books is a "myth"?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/52111/is-it-true-that-the-need-for-marketing-promoting-ones-books-is-a-myth)

Comment: I've seen you created a new question on this topic which is pratically a the same, so I flagged this as a dublicate (the above comment is auto-generated). I posted my answer along with other users on the newer question.

Comment: Thanks, Matt. I decided to ask it again in a different way because I thought perhaps my wording was the problem.